# Python 3.4: min and max of lists within a list incorrect

Tags: python, max, min, nested-lists

1. I am creating code that outputs the minimum and maximum score of each student. The code firstly reads from the file an then stores it in a list:

[['Georgina Cottrell', '4', '10', '8'], ['Amelia Cox', '6', '4', '8'], ['Jack Elsom', '8', '9', '10'], ['Isabella Jones', '2', '8', '4']]

When trying to find the min and max, it only works for certain lists.  Here is an example of an output:

[['Amelia Cox', 6, 4, 8, 4, 6], ['Georgina Cottrell', 4, 10, 8, 4, 10], ['Isabella Jones', 2, 8, 4, 2, 8], ['Jack Elsom', 8, 9, 10, 8, 9]]

As you can see my code isnt recognising some of the minimums and some of the maximums.

Here is my code:

```
    def menu():
        global user_password
        if user_password == correct_password:
            classes = input("Which class would you like to view? :")
            classes = classes.lower()
            while classes not in ["3a", "4a", "5a"]:
                time.sleep(2)
                classes = input("Input invalid. Please enter 3a, 4a or 5a: ")
                if classes == ["3a", "4a", "5a"]:
                    break
            if classes == "3a":
                file = open("scores3a.csv", "r")
                csv_f = csv.reader(file)
                yourlists = list(csv_f)
                file.close()
                yourlists2 = [x for x in yourlists if x]
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                      "Welcome to the menu sytem to view your students scores.\n"
                      "-------------------------------------------------------------\n"
                      "Type the corresponding letter for what you would like to view:\n")
                time.sleep(2)
                all_scores = print("Input 'a' to see all of your students scores in alphabetical order(by forename)\n"
                                   "and sorted into highest to lowest scores for each student")
        time.sleep(2)
        highest_scores = print("Input 'b' to see all of the students average scores\n"
                               "sorted into highest to lowest")
                user = input()
                if user == "a":
                    yourlists2.sort()
                    slices = yourlists2[0][:]
                    slices1 = yourlists2[1][:]
                    slices2 = yourlists2[2][:]
                    slices3 = yourlists2[3][:]
                    for row in slices:
                        slices[1]=int(slices[1])
                        slices[2]=int(slices[2])
                        slices[3]=int(slices[3])
                        lowest = min(slices[1:3])
                        slices.append(lowest)
                        highest =  max(slices[1:3])
                        slices.append(highest)
                        break
                    for row in slices1:
                        slices1[1]=int(slices1[1])
                        slices1[2]=int(slices1[2])
                        slices1[3]=int(slices1[3])
                        lowest = min(slices1[1:3])
                        slices1.append(lowest)
                        highest =  max(slices1[1:3])
                        slices1.append(highest)
                        break
                    for row in slices2:
                        slices2[1]=int(slices2[1])
                        slices2[2]=int(slices2[2])
                        slices2[3]=int(slices2[3])
                        lowest = min(slices2[1:3])
                        slices2.append(lowest)
                        highest =  max(slices2[1:3])
                        slices2.append(highest)
                        break
                    for row in slices3:
                        slices3[1]=int(slices3[1])
                        slices3[2]=int(slices3[2])
                        slices3[3]=int(slices3[3])
                        lowest = min(slices3[1:3])
                        slices3.append(lowest)
                        highest =  max(slices3[1:3])
                        slices3.append(highest)
                        break
                    yourlists2=[slices,slices1,slices2,slices3]
                    print(yourlists2)


    menu()
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Note that `slices[1:3]` is a list of length 2: it only contains `slices[1]` and `slices[2]` (the end index is not inclusive).  You probably want `slices[1:]` or `slices[1:4]` instead.

Comment: Of course!  This has been bugging me for days, and it was just this simple!  Thank you so much.